# System.Type.ForName(namespace, classname) this method is taking about 30 secs to execute

Tags: apex, api

System.Type.ForName(namespace, classname) is taking a lot of time to execute. Could this be because of the code present in  ?

Comment: If it is Aura or LWC then you can check if there is any blocking operation OR if there are other calls being boxed along with the call you are making. You should be able to see it from the Network tab of browser in Request and Request params and timings tab.

Comment: @manjit5190 after debugging, I found that it was taking time to execute System.Type.ForName(namespace, classname) this method. Any idea what can cause this method to take so long to execute? Could there be a problem with the class <classname>?